# Is it possible to show a window in front of the Start screen?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, interop, startmenu

Is it possible to show a window on top of the Start screen in Windows 8? So far I've tried

```
this.TopMost = true;
```

But it does not work.

Comment: it would seem that what you want is for your app to have a higher priority. look here for a starting place. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778006/how-to-draw-above-windows-8-metro-interface

Comment: Thanks, too hard to be done, I was trying to add commands in the user picture menu from the Start screen, but Micorsoft made it to hard to accomplish. I am not going to pay for a certificate in order to release a freeware... Windows is becoming more and more iOS like... XP days were so beautiful...

Comment: No it's not possible.

Comment: Yes its possible. DUO.com have an app which prevents you from logging into Windows via the start screen until you complete their 2 factor authentication. Their form is also a modal so you cannot access anything else until you complete it.

Comment: Yeah, 10 years later now I know as well how to do it. Research has been done and new knowledge is available, which was not back then. Useful read: https://blog.adeltax.com/window-z-order-in-windows-10/